# Best way to store 100,000+ CSV text files on server?

Tags: sqlite, file, storage, scalability

We have an application which will need to store thousands of fairly small CSV files. 100,000+ and growing annually by the same amount.  Each file contains around 20-80KB of vehicle tracking data.  Each data set (or file) represents a single vehicle journey.

We are currently storing this information in SQL Server, but the size of the database is getting a little unwieldy and we only ever need to access the journey data one file at time (so the need to query it in bulk or otherwise store in a relational database is not needed). The performance of the database is degrading as we add more tracks, due to the time taken to rebuild or update indexes when inserting or deleting data.

There are 3 options we are considering:

1. We could use the FILESTREAM feature of SQL to externalise the data into files, but I've not used this feature before.  Would Filestream still result in one physical file per database object (blob)?
2. Alternatively, we could store the files individually on disk. There
   could end being half a million of them after 3+ years.  Will the
   NTFS file system cope OK with this amount?
3. If lots of files is a problem, should we consider grouping the datasets/files into a small database (one peruser) so that each user? Is there a very lightweight database like SQLite that can store files?

One further point: the data is highly compressible. Zipping the files reduces them to only 10% of their original size. I would like to utilise compression if possible to minimise disk space used and backup size.

Comment: `The performance of the database is degrading as we add more tracks` did you consider adding proper indexing on the database instead of switching to csv files? If speed is the main problem that would help if the main concern is disk space (which is uncommon imho) then switching away from db might help you (though I doubt the impact will be huge)

Comment: I'm not a SQL expert but I think it's hard to get decent insert performance on a table which has millions of rows (each representing one line of a 10,000 line CSV file). We had considereed it, but then we're not really sure why these particular data items even need to be in the database.

Comment: There are also other issues such as the volume of data will bloat the size of the backups unnecessarily, with tonnes of data which never changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few thoughts, and this is very subjective, so your mileage ond other readers' mileage may vary, but hopefully it will still get the ball rolling for you even if other folks want to put differing points of view...

Firstly, I have seen performance issues with folders containing too many files. One project got around this by creating 256 directories, called 00, 01, 02... fd, fe, ff and inside each one of those a further 256 directories with the same naming convention. That potentially divides your 500,000 files across 65,536 directories giving you only a few in each - if you use a good hash/random generator to spread them out. Also, the filenames are pretty short to store in your database - e.g. `32/af/file-xyz.csv`. Doubtless someone will bite my head off, but I feel 10,000 files in one directory is plenty to be going on with.

Secondly, 100,000 files of 80kB amounts to 8GB of data which is really not very big these days - a small USB flash drive in fact - so I think any arguments about compression are not that valid - storage is cheap. What could be important though, is backup. If you have 500,000 files you have lots of 'inodes' to traverse and I think the statistic used to be that many backup products can only traverse 50-100 'inodes' per second - so you are going to be waiting a very long time. Depending on the downtime you can tolerate, it may be better to take the system offline and back up from the raw, block device - at say 100MB/s you can back up 8GB in 80 seconds and I can't imagine a traditional, file-based backup can get close to that. Alternatives may be a filesysten that permits snapshots and then you can backup from a snapshot. Or a mirrored filesystem which permits you to split the mirror, backup from one copy and then rejoin the mirror.

As I said, pretty subjective and I am sure others will have other ideas.

Comment: Thanks, we can potentially create folders based on the company id and user id to avoid that problem (no single user will have that many files). So we'd end up with co9665\user21043\track1.zip  That will also mean it's easy to quickly delete all of the data for a user or company, should they stop using the system.

Comment: I hadn't even thought about backup so that's a good point. Ideally I'd like to see if there's a way to easily combine the files into larger ones, without creating too much work or overhead. Eg perhaps one file per month or something.

Answer (score 1):

I work on an application that uses a hybrid approach, primarily because we wanted our application to be able to work (in small installations) in freebie versions of SQL Server...and the file load would have thrown us over the top quickly.  We have gobs of files - tens of millions in large installations.

We considered the same scenarios you've enumerated, but what we eventually decided to do was to have a series of moderately large (2gb) memory mapped files that contain the would-be files as opaque blobs.  Then, in the database, the blobs are keyed by blob-id (a sha1 hash of the uncompressed blob), and have fields for the container-file-id, offset, length, and uncompressed-length.  There's also a "published" flag in the blob-referencing table.  Because the hash faithfully represents the content, a blob is only ever written once.  Modified files produce new hashes, and they're written to new locations in the blob store.

In our case, the blobs weren't consistently text files - in fact, they're chunks of files of all types.  Big files are broken up with a rolling-hash function into roughly 64k chunks.  We attempt to compress each blob with lz4 compression (which is way fast compression - and aborts quickly on effectively-incompressible data).

This approach works really well, but isn't lightly recommended.  It can get complicated.  For example, grooming the container files in the face of deleted content.  For this, we chose to use sparse files and just tell NTFS the extents of deleted blobs.  Transactional demands are more complicated.

All of the goop for db-to-blob-store is c# with a little interop for the memory-mapped files.  Your scenario sounds similar, but somewhat less demanding.  I suspect you could get away without the memory-mapped I/O complications.